# QuotedPrintableCodec doesn't works

Tags: java, decoding

I still have problems with decode a string that type is Quoted Printable. Now, I'm using the QuotedPrintableCodec class, but the problem continues.

I have a method:

```
  public static String decodeString(String str){
    try {
        return new String(QuotedPrintableCodec.decodeQuotedPrintable(str.getBytes("ISO_8859_1")), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    } catch (DecoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Ex: I received this string: "**RÃ©u:**" and the decoded string should be like: "**Réu:**".
But this method returns the same string "RÃ©u:"
I use this webSite to see if the strings can be decoded:

http://www.convertstring.com/pt_PT/EncodeDecode/QuotedPrintableDecode

I tried to use URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8") and not works too.

Comment: RÃ©u is not at all in quoted-printable format, so using this class is unable to help you with this problem. Try focusing on understand character encodings and how they work in Java, then using the right one (which is UTF-8)

Comment: I tried with URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF- 8") and it is not works too

Comment: I know. I said learn how character encodings work in Java, I didn't say that a specific class will solve your problem. You didn't show enough of your problem for anyone to tell where exactly it is. Your only solution is to educate yourself about character encodings and how they work in Java (or just show your complete problem that we can completely reproduce)